# What do the terms "mean fit" and "mean fit ratio" describe?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, terminology, latent-semantic-analysis

I am reading some Matlab code provided by authors that implements the generalized EM algorithm from the paper [Modeling Hidden Topics on Document Manifold](https://public.websites.umich.edu/%7Eqmei/pub/cikm2008-cai.pdf).
The regularized log-likelihood of the model is
$$\mathfrak{L} = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^M n(d_i, w_j) \log \sum_{k=1}^K P(w_j | z_k) P(z_k | d_i) - \lambda \sum_{k=1}^K \mathcal{R}_k,$$
where $\mathcal{R}_k = \frac12 \sum_{i,j=1}^N W_{ij} \left( P(z_k | d_i) - P(z_k | d_j) \right)^2$.

They define variables `meanFit` and `meanFitRatio`. They set `meanFitRatio = 0.1` and its value never changes. Initially, they set `meanFit = Obj*10;` where `Obj` corresponds to the value of $\mathfrak{L}$, and `meanFit` is updated in one of the following ways:

1. `meanFit = 10*Obj(end);`, or
2. `meanFit = meanFitRatio*meanFit + (1-meanFitRatio)*Obj(end);`,

depending on some conditions I cannot make sense of.

They don't seem to be widely used terms. The authors don't use these terms in their paper so it is not clear to me what the terms "mean fit" and "mean fit ratio" are supposed to represent. I am hoping someone has an idea on what these terms may represent in the context of maximum likelihood estimation.